# PostgreSQL - Filtering join using date ranges by group

Tags: postgresql, date, join, filter

I have two tables:

**Table 1**: A table containing a listing of event occurrences with unique IDs per unique event (`event_id`), the date of the event (`date_event`), and each person's gender (`gender`):

```
person| event_id| date_event | gender|
----- |---------|------------|-------|
a     |  86i    | 2012-01-25 |   m   |
a     |  87i    | 2012-05-30 |   m   |
a     |  88i    | 2012-09-20 |   m   |
a     |  89i    | 2012-12-20 |   m   |
b     |  15i    | 2015-04-06 |   f   |
b     |  16i    | 2016-07-06 |   f   |
b     |  17i    | 2016-04-30 |   f   |
b     |  18i    | 2016-11-28 |   f   |
----- |---------|------------|-------|
```

**Table 2**: A table of dates listing the start dates (`date_start`) and end dates (`date_end`), representing ranges of time in which each person was enrolled in a program:

```
person| date_start | date_end   |
----- |------------|------------|
a     | 2012-02-05 | 2012-03-30 |
a     | 2012-06-26 | 2012-08-28 |
a     | 2012-09-15 | 2012-12-31 |
b     | 2015-01-24 | 2015-03-30 |
b     | 2016-07-01 | 2016-10-01 |
b     | 2016-11-25 | 2016-12-30 |
----- |------------|------------|
```

I would like to be able to filter Table 1 to only contain records of events that occurred when the person was enrolled in a program, which would be specified as `date_event` being between `date_start` and `date_end`. My desired resulting table would look like:

**Desired result**:

```
person| event_id| date_event | gender|
----- |---------|------------|-------|
a     |  88i    | 2012-09-20 |   m   |
a     |  89i    | 2012-12-20 |   m   |
b     |  16i    | 2016-07-06 |   f   |
b     |  18i    | 2016-11-28 |   f   |
----- |---------|------------|-------|
```

I have tried several variations of the following to no avail:

```
CREATE TABLE temptable AS
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
USING(person);

CREATE TABLE desiredresult AS
SELECT * 
FROM temptable 
WHERE date_event BETWEEN date_start AND date_end
GROUP BY person;
```

I will admit that I am definitely a SQL novice and am used to using R where I can achieve my desired result using the below code. However, the dataset I'm using is gigantic so I need to figure out how to perform these operations on a SQL server.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

desiredresult <- table1 %>%
    left_join(table2) %>%
    group_by(person) %>%
    mutate(keep_record = date_event %within% interval(start_date, end_date)) %>%
    filter(keep_record == TRUE)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for creating a temp table, and spend the processing time doing so. Just select directly from the JOIN.  (See [Demd](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3db143a8a58f36eb1c88a1b7ec7991cb))

```
select t1.* 
  from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 
    on (     t1.person = t2.person
         and t1.date_event between t2.date_start and t2.date_end 
       ) ;
```